# ng2-charts / chart.js - How to set doughnut/pie chart color on specific labels programatically?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a list of transactions which return `status` as chart labels and `count` as chart data. My labels are often `['cancelled', 'completed', 'rejected']`, but sometimes the data returns `['cancelled', 'completed', 'error', 'pending', 'rejected]`. How to set different color for each label?

My code so far:

```
statusCount: StatusCount[] = [];
  loaded = false;

  // Doughnut
  public chartData = [];
  public chartLabels = [];

  public chartType = 'doughnut';

  public chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
   }
  };

  private chartColors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: ['#E91E63', '#00BFA5', '#ff1744'] }];

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTransactionStatus();
  }

  getTransactionStatus() {
    this.apiService.getTransactionStatus().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.statusCount = res;
      for (const i of this.statusCount) {
        this.chartData.push(i.count);
        this.chartLabels.push(i.status);
      }
      this.loaded = true;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `chartColors` also in your `getTransactionStatus` method.

It would look something like this (assuming that your `statusCount` object has a color property:

```
public chartColors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: [] }];

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTransactionStatus();
  }

  getTransactionStatus() {
    this.apiService.getTransactionStatus().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.statusCount = res;
      for (const i of this.statusCount) {
        this.chartData.push(i.count);
        this.chartLabels.push(i.status);
        this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor.push(i.color);
      }
      this.loaded = true;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Note that your `chartColors` object should be public (like the `chartData`, `chartLabelse`, etc.) to be visible to the HTML (it will work in dev mode but it won't build unless it is public.